# Type 'ValueGetterFunc' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have some Angular 13 Code which i am trying to return a column definition which includes a valueGetter which is a function and that's where I run into an issue.

Below is a sample function i like to pass in from my api

```
  getSellerAgentandOffice(params: ValueGetterParams) {
        console.log('Calling Value Getter')
        return params.data.ListAgentFirstName + ' ' + params.data.ListAgentLastName ;
      }
```

to do so i would use below code to return it

```
private createColumnDefs(columnsList: IGridColumnAgGrid[] = this.columnsList) {
        console.log(this.columnsList)
        let valueGetterFunction 
        this.gridColumnDefs = columnsList.map((column) => {
            return {
                colId: column.colId,
                headerName: column.headerName,
                valueGetter: this.getSellerAgentandOffice,
```

This works fine but i need it more dynamic so i tried the following which creates this error.

```
valueGetter:this[column.valueGetter]
```

[image]

Based on that i tried a few other things like

```
 let valueGetterFunction 
        this.gridColumnDefs = columnsList.map((column) => {
            if(column.valueGetter ==="getSellerAgentandOffice") {
                    valueGetterFunction = this[column.valueGetter]
            }

 valueGetter: this[valueGetterFunction],
```

this one works but if I get rid of the `if(column.valueGetter ==="getSellerAgentandOffice") or make it a  if(column.valueGetter !=="getSellerAgentandOffice")`

So i am a bit confused on how to fix this issue or if there is even a simple fix other then
do a bunch of if's to assign the function.

Here is a working sample that shows the issue
[Stackblitz Sample Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-3ugco1?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: you wanna call a function based on `column.valueGetter`?

Comment: the value of valueGetter on the column object holds the name of the function i want to assign to the valueGetter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case if someone should run into a similar issue below is the code that fix the issue as i guess the error was due to fact that it could be possibly undefined or nothing.

```
 const valueGetter =   column.valueGetter as string;
 valueGetterFunction = this[valueGetter] || '';
```